# What is the term when you are replacing a name with a noun?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, terminology, parts-of-speech

What is the term used when replacing a name for a noun? Example Mrs. Lewis walked in.---> The teacher walked in.

Comment: I would like to call it denominalization. Unfortunately that word has already been hijacked for another use.

Comment: Why do you need a word for this process of replacement?

Comment: @user140679 Whenever a proper name is replaced with a common noun, we just avoid a repetition of the proper name. Such replacement is obviously possible when there is identity of subjects (or objects): Mrs. Lewis, the teacher, walked in. I've thought of the term "deproperization", but that would be the case when a proper name is converted into a common noun, as in "I have two Rembrandts".

Answer (score 1):

The most common term for it seems to be *antonomasia*, which the *Oxford English Dictionary* [defines](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8937) as:

> 1. The substitution of an epithet or title for a proper name. Also: the substituted epithet itself.
> 2. The use of the proper name of a particular individual as a generic term to denote others who belong to an implied type; an instance of this.

(The sense you want is #1.)

According to the *OED*, another term for it (in both senses) is *pronomination*; and one source also claims that *periphrasis* has these senses [[link](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/P/periphrasis.htm)], though in my experience *periphrasis* is usually much more general (and the *OED* does not list such a specific sense for it).